# Knockout.js: Getting values of observables from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, knockout.js, data-binding

Using Knockout, I'm attempting to update the value of a data-bind with the value from a JSON object on mouseover. I feel I have a fundamental lack of understanding here. Where am I going wrong?

```
(function($, ko, test) {
    var self = this;
    self.text = ko.observable();

    var MV = function() {

        $.getJSON('data.json')
        .then(function (data) {
            self.data = data;
            return self.data;
        });

        self.mouseOver = function() {
            self.text = ko.observable(self.data[0]);
        }

    };

    $(function() {
        test.mv = new MV();
        ko.applyBindings(test.mv, document.getElementById('wrapper'));
    });

}(jQuery, ko, window));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
(function($, ko, test) {
    var MV = function() {
        var self = this;
        self.text = ko.observable();
        self.data = ko.observableArray();
        $.getJSON('data.json')
        .then(function (data) {
            self.data(data);
        });

        self.mouseOver = function() {
            self.text(self.data()[0]);
      }

  };

    $(function() {
        test.mv = new MV();
        ko.applyBindings(test.mv, document.getElementById('wrapper'));
    });

}(jQuery, ko, window));
```